# update markers on google maps using php and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, google-maps

hello I made a code to open a webpage that contain the map with coordinates placed in a database I want to auto update the map with new markers of the new coordinates from that database 
here is the code in php please help me

```
<?php

// read data 
$account =mysql_connect("localhost","username","password")
or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("first",$account);

$sql ="SELECT * FROM test";

$result=mysql_query($sql,$account);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$Lo=$row['one'];
$Lat=$row['two'];


}
echo $Lo.'and '.$Lat.'<br>';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>

<script>

var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng('<?php echo $Lo; ?>','<?php echo $Lat; ?>');

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:myCenter,
  zoom:9,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter,
  });

marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
</body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

So I finally did it :D . With help form various different sources and all! here us the complete code :

```html
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("vsms3") or die(mysql_error());
?>

<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google Maps</title>

<!-------- Customizable Css for Map  ----------------------------->
    <style type="text/css">
        body { font: normal 10pt Helvetica, Arial; }
        #map { width: 500px; height: 300px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; }
    </style>

    <!---------------- Java Scripts for Map  ----------------->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDzaa4MZ7r4s26i54PwErpKTynKAaWVxTc&v=3&language=en"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <!------------- Java Scripts for Map  ------------------->
    <script type="text/javascript">
var marker;
var map = null;
var markersArray = [];

    //--------------------- Sample code written by vIr ------------
    var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
               new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
               new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
                    var center = null;
                    
                    var currentPopup;
                    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                    function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
                        var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                        bounds.extend(pt);
       marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: pt,
       draggable: true,
       raiseOnDrag: true,
                            icon: icon,
                            map: map
                        });
       markersArray.push(marker);
                        var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content: info,
                            maxWidth: 300
                        });
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                            if (currentPopup != null) {
                                currentPopup.close();
                                currentPopup = null;
                            }
                            popup.open(map, marker);
                            currentPopup = popup;
                        });
                        google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
                            map.panTo(center);
                            currentPopup = null;
                        });
                    }
        
                    function initMap() {
                        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {

                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
                            zoom: 14,
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                            mapTypeControl: true,
                            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
                            },
                            navigationControl: true,
                            navigationControlOptions: {
                                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN
                            }
                        });
   

  setInterval(function mapload(){
 
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST", 
       url: 'location.php',
         // data: form_data,
       success: function(data)
       {
        
         // var json_obj = $.parseJSON(data);//parse JSON
        var json_obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
        for (var i in json_obj) 
        { addMarker(json_obj[i].u_lat, json_obj[i].u_lon,"Longitude:" + json_obj[i].u_lon + "<br>" + json_obj[i].u_email + "<br>" + json_obj[i].u_name);
        
        }
       },
       dataType: "json"//set to JSON    
      })    
 
   
  },3000);

   center = bounds.getCenter();
   map.fitBounds(bounds);

   }
  

    setInterval(function removeMarker() {
    if (markersArray) {
        for (i=0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
            markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    marker=null;
        }
    markersArray.length = 0;
    }
},3000);
   </script>

  </head>
    <body onLoad="initMap()" style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px;">
       <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

and the database related page :

```html
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("vsms3") or die(mysql_error());
$data = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users")or die(mysql_error());
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);

   //echo("addMarker($lat, $lon, '<b>$name</b><br />$desc');\n");
?>
```